# Better way to get total of different items in loop?

Tags: javascript

The following is working, no errors. But It's crazy long, not a real js developer here, so I did it the way I knew it. But I am pretty sure this can be resolved much, much easier and shorter.

We have data in `countData` and I loop it. For each data within `countData` I need to do "***last item minus previous to last item***", basically I need to do `today - yesterday`.

The way I'm doing is simple, I loop countData, get the `previous to last item` and `push it to its corresponding array`, do the same for the last item and then get the `sum of today` and `sum of yesterday` arrays and do `today - yesterday` for each item in order to know how many items we had between yesterday and today.

Is there any better way both for performance and style not to mention code length? I just would like to learn better ways to do it and study them.

**NOTE**:

`countData` is an index within the main loop for ALL states `for (var a = 0; a < filtererdData.length; ++a) {var countData = filtererdData[a];...` and I am running this bit on here within that for loop

```
var todayTeraphy = [];
var todaySintomi = [];
var todayHospital = [];
var todayHome = [];
var todayPositive = [];
var todayRecovered = [];
var todayDeaths = [];
var todayConfirmed = [];
var todaySwabs = [];

var yesterdayTeraphy = [];
var yesterdaySintomi = [];
var yesterdayHospital = [];
var yesterdayHome = [];
var yesterdayPositive = [];
var yesterdayRecovered = [];
var yesterdayDeaths = [];
var yesterdayConfirmed = [];
var yesterdaySwabs = [];

for (var i = 0; i < countData.length; ++i) {
    if(i == countData.length-2) {
        yesterdayTeraphy.push(countData[i].terapia_intensiva);
        yesterdaySintomi.push(countData[i].ricoverati_con_sintomi);
        yesterdayHospital.push(countData[i].totale_ospedalizzati);
        yesterdayHome.push(countData[i].isolamento_domiciliare);
        yesterdayPositive.push(countData[i].totale_positivi);
        yesterdayRecovered.push(countData[i].dimessi_guariti);
        yesterdayDeaths.push(countData[i].deceduti);
        yesterdayConfirmed.push(countData[i].totale_casi);
        yesterdaySwabs.push(countData[i].tamponi);
    }
    if(i == countData.length-1) {
        todayTeraphy.push(countData[i].terapia_intensiva);
        todaySintomi.push(countData[i].ricoverati_con_sintomi);
        todayHospital.push(countData[i].totale_ospedalizzati);
        todayHome.push(countData[i].isolamento_domiciliare);
        todayPositive.push(countData[i].totale_positivi);
        todayRecovered.push(countData[i].dimessi_guariti);
        todayDeaths.push(countData[i].deceduti);
        todayConfirmed.push(countData[i].totale_casi);
        todaySwabs.push(countData[i].tamponi);
    }
}

var totTodayTeraphy = todayTeraphy.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayTeraphy = yesterdayTeraphy.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totTeraphy = totTodayTeraphy - totYesterdayTeraphy;

var totTodaySintomi = todaySintomi.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdaySintomi = yesterdaySintomi.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totSintomi = totTodaySintomi - totYesterdaySintomi;

var totTodayHospital = todayHospital.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayHospital = yesterdayHospital.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totHospital = totTodayHospital - totYesterdayHospital;

var totTodayHome = todayHome.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayHome = yesterdayHome.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totHome = totTodayHome - totYesterdayHome;

var totTodayPositive = todayPositive.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayPositive = yesterdayPositive.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totPositivi = totTodayPositive - totYesterdayPositive;

var totTodayRecovered = todayRecovered.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayRecovered = yesterdayRecovered.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totRecovered = totTodayRecovered - totYesterdayRecovered;

var totTodayDeaths = todayDeaths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayDeaths = yesterdayDeaths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totDeaths = totTodayDeaths - totYesterdayDeaths;

var totTodayConfirmed = todayConfirmed.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdayConfirmed = yesterdayConfirmed.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totConfirmed = totTodayConfirmed - totYesterdayConfirmed;

var totTodaySwabs = todaySwabs.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totYesterdaySwabs = yesterdaySwabs.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
var totSwabs = totTodaySwabs - totYesterdaySwabs;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each state, you're only interested in the final two items in its `countData` array, so there's no need for a nested loop. For example, rather than

```
for (var i = 0; i < countData.length; ++i) {
  if (i == countData.length - 2) {
    yesterdayTeraphy.push(countData[i].terapia_intensiva);
    yesterdaySintomi.push(countData[i].ricoverati_con_sintomi);
    // ...
```

you can do

```
const len = countData.length;
yesterdayTeraphy.push(countData[len - 2].terapia_intensiva);
yesterdaySintomi.push(countData[len - 2].ricoverati_con_sintomi);
// ...
```

But, to go further - since you're using the same sort of thing with the 2nd last day and the last day, you can abstract it into a function. Also, rather than having so many individual variable names, you can have an *object* containing the cumulative count for each day, eg:

```
// cumulativeToday:
{
  hospital: 10,
  home: 20,
  // ...
}
```

To construct such an object concisely, create a map of the italian words (the dataset properties) to the English property name you want:

```
const italianToEnglish = {
  totale_ospedalizzati: 'hospital',
  isolamento_domiciliare: 'home',
  // ...
};
const cumulativeYesterday = {};
const cumulativeToday = {};

const addToCumulative = (cumulative, stateDay) => {
  for (const [italian, english] of Object.entries(italianToEnglish)) {
    cumulative[english] = (cumulative[english] || 0) + stateDay[italian];
  }
};
for (const stateArr of filtererdData) {
  addToCumulative(cumulativeToday, stateArr.pop());
  addToCumulative(cumulativeYesterday, stateArr.pop());
}
```

Then, to construct the differences (eg `var totSwabs = totTodaySwabs - totYesterdaySwabs;`), iterate over the `italianToEnglish` object and subtract the `cumulativeYesterday` value from the `cumulativeToday` value:

```
const diffs = {};
for (const [key, todayValue] of Object.entries(cumulativeToday)) {
  diffs[key] = todayValue - cumulativeYesterday[key];
}
```

With this approach, for example, data previously in `totTodaySwabs` will be in `cumulativeToday.swabs`, `totYesterdaySwabs` will be in `cumulativeYesterday.swabs`, `totSwabs` will be in `diffs.swabs`.

Note that it's a *lot* nicer-looking to iterate over arrays using `for..of` than ordinary `for` loops, which require manual iteration and can get pretty ugly.

Also note that `const` should be strongly preferred over `var` in modern Javascript - `const` variables tell the reader of the code that the variable is not going to be reassigned, which makes things easier to read (one less thing to have to worry about while analyzing the code).

If code is going to need to run on ancient browsers which don't support ES2015 syntax like `const`, the best solution for maintainable code is to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to automatically transpile to ES5 for production, while keeping the source code concise and modern.

Comment: It's super elegant, and makes it a lot nicer and easier indeed. The only bit I don't get is english to italian, because in reality I only have italian like `ieriTerapia.push` not `yesterdayTeraphy.push` I have translated it here for everyone to understand it. Not sure if this changes your code

Comment: It depends on the properties in your desired output structure. If it's going to be the same as in the input dataset, there's no need for the object. If the properties are sometimes going to be different from those in the input, regardless of language, it will still be useful to concisely transform the input property name to the desired property name.

Comment: ehmm, maybe you're right, I actually have 2 maps, italian and global, while in italiani "Guariti" is always "Guariti", when we switch to the global map, we actually have "Recovered", same thing for Deaths and Cases (wish we had more data for covid-19 as we have per the italian as the questions shows). Thanks a lot